# How does a CUDA device function work?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Does the CUDA device function call (defined with `__device__`) from kernel works similar to the host function i.e., Does it involve the pushing of the return address on the stack and pushing the variables on the stack and retrieving on the return ?

If yes, then which memory is used in this case for stack ? (cache, shared or global)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `__device__` function can be either inlined or not (this is also true of host functions, generally speaking).

If the function is inlined, there is no stack usage.

If the function is not inlined, there is stack usage.

The stack is a per-thread stack, and it lives in the logical space called "local" memory, which is managed by the thread in the same physical memory where the logical space called "global" memory lives, i.e. the on-board GPU DRAM.

There are nuances as to whether a function will be inlined or not, you may want to read the relevant doc [section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#noinline-and-forceinline).

You can read more about local memory [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) (scroll down to the local memory section).